# Nodejs - login with company emails

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, authentication, web

I am building a web portal for my company using Node.js and want only people having the emails |name at company-name dot com| to be able to login.

Underneath our email system is supported by Gmail.

How can I achieve that in Nodejs.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

A basic way to check if the email contains `@companyname.com` is to use a RegExp. By following the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/RegExp):

```
var COMPANY_NAME = 'companyname';
var DOMAIN_EXTENSION = 'com';

var emailRegExp = new RegExp('^.+@' + COMPANY_NAME + '\.' + DOMAIN_EXTENSION + '$'); // /^.+@companyname\.com$/

if ('toto@companyname.com'.match(emailRegExp) !== null) {
    console.log('The email is matching!');
} else {
    console.log('The email is wrong.');
}
```